# Add new line in text file without changing the format

Tags: batch

This is my script:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET origfile="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test1\before.txt" 
SET tempfile="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\test1\after.txt" 
SET insertbefore=4 
FOR /F %%C IN ('FIND /C /V "" ^<%origfile%') DO SET totallines=%%C 

<%origfile% (FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%totallines%) DO ( 
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
  SET /P L= 
  IF %%i==%insertbefore% ECHO( 
  ECHO(!L! 
  ENDLOCAL 
)
) >%tempfile% 
COPY /Y %tempfile% %origfile% >NUL 
DEL %tempfile% 
pause
```

I saved this as `run1.bat`. After running, I have a problem with the format, it is out of order.

Original file:

```
header 1<--here got tab delimited format--><--here got tab delimited format--> 
header 2<--here got tab delimited format--><--here got tab delimited format-->
header 3<--here got tab delimited format--><--here got tab delimited format-->
details 1
details 2
```

Output:

```
header 1<--tab delimited is missing--><--tab delimited is missing--> 
header 2<--tab delimited is missing--><--tab delimited is missing-->
header 3<--tab delimited is missing--><--tab delimited is missing-->

details 1
details 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) installed, you can use the following **command** in a Command Prompt window:

```
perl -p -i -e "print qq(\n) if $. == 4" filename.txt
```

I'm sure you can do it with batch scripts but sometimes I think it just isn't worth the effort.

---

Update 1:

To make the above into a file that can be used like your bat file you could create a **script file** "insert4.pl" as follows

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'before.txt'    or die "can't read before.txt because $!\n";
open my $out, '>', 'after.txt'    or die "can't write after.txt because $!\n";    

while (<$in>) {
  print $out $_;
  print "\n" if $. == 4;
}

close $out;
close $in;

unlink 'before.txt'               or die "can't delete before.txt because $!\n";
rename 'after.txt', 'before.txt'  or die "can't rename temp file because $!\n";
```

(untested)

---

Update 2:

When you install the Perl interpreter, it should automatically associate the `.pl` filename extension with Perl scripts to be run by the Perl interpreter. You should be able to confirm this with `assoc .pl`, If it says ".pl=perlscript", check `ftype perlscript`.

The installer should also add the perl interpreter's location to the command search `PATH` used by Windows' Command-Prompt.

Perl scripts should be saved in files with a filename extension of `.pl`.

If all the above is OK, you can run perl scripts by just typing their filename `myscript.pl` otherwise you have to explicitly tell Windows what interpreter to use: `perl myscript.pl` or in the worst case `C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl myscript.pl`.

Comment: thanks for ur reply RedGrittyBrick.

i save this script as run2.bat and it come out with error msg ('perl' is not as an internal or external command.

this is my script


<code>perl -p -i -e "print qq(\n) if $. == 4" C:\Documents and Settings\Mun Kar\Desktop\test1\file1.txt

pause <code>

Comment: @newbie: Sorry, you need to download and install the [Perl interpreter](http://strawberryperl.com/) before you can run Perl scripts. What I quoted was a command but it is not hard to make it into the equivalent of a bat file, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: is Perl interpreter is freeware or i need to pay before use?

Comment: The Perl interpreter is free, there is nothing to pay. If you were in a commercial business context where you needed a commercially supported product, you could buy support from [Activestate](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl?gclid=CNunyvnxmasCFUQMfAodHhAbiQ) - they also provide a free version.

Comment: after running, still have error come out '#!perl' is not as an internal or external command. after installed this software

Comment: (1) what is the response to the command `perl -v`?   (2) try the command I gave at the top of the answer.   (3) ensure you saved the script as `something.pl` with a filename-extension of `.pl`. If typing (or clicking a shortcut to) `something.pl` still says `#!perl` is not a ... command` try typing `perl something.pl`.

Comment: sorry i think im  make mistake..im still testing

Comment: which mean i must create 2 files? 1 file is 'perl -p -i -e "print qq(\n) if $. == 4" filename.txt' and 2nd file is insert4.pl

i need to go out for a while..come back in shortly

Comment: No, you don't need to create any files at all. Just open a Command Prompt window and *carefully* type the one-line command `perl -p -i -e "print qq(\n) if $. == 4" Desktop\test1\before.txt` as a command and press Enter.

Comment: Im back...error msg (Can't do inplace edit without backup)

so, every time to open and type this command?

Comment: (1) "Can't do inplace edit without backups" - change `-i` to `-i.bak`. (2) "so, every time to open and type this command?" - what do you want to do instead?

Comment: it works perfectly...and make it as a batch file...thanks RedGrittyBrick